# How to pass command line arguments using vs code debugger

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm having trouble debugging a simple C program where it receives command line arguments, although I can compile the code and it is working, I wanted to debug step by step.

This is how my `launch.json` look like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": ["arg1" "arg2"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted to pass command line arguments for example:

`./a.out "Hello" "How are you"`

However, when I try to debug nothings happens.

Comment: how do you try to debug?, why not create a `preLaunchTask`, what is the error you get?

Comment: When you say the C code compiles and is working... how have you verified it? I it possible that there's a mistake on that side?

Comment: what's up with your `"args": ["arg1" "arg2"],` and why aren't you using that to pass the arguments you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your arguments inside the "args" array in the debug configuration.

Like this

```
"args": ["--key": "value"]
```